# Net::Server SSL server tip needed

Tags: perl, ssl, tcp

I am building a preforking SSL server using Net::Server module.
A client will transmit binary data, either openeing a new connection for each dataset or letting the connection open persistently.

The data is of dynamic lenght, with an header specifying the payload length.

Questions:

- what is the recommended way of reading the data, to support also persistent connection?
- how can I determine if the SSL session was properly established by the client, before actually starting to receive data?

Code template:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use common::sense;

use IO::Socket;
use base qw(Net::Server::PreForkSimple);

my $sslErrorCallback = 'ssl_error_callback';
__PACKAGE__->run(
  port => "*:12345:ssleay:IPv4",
  SSL_key_file => "server.pem",
  SSL_cert_file => "server.crt",
  SSL_error_callback => \&$sslErrorCallback,
);
exit;

################################################################################

sub ssl_error_callback {
  print STDERR "SSL failed; Data::Dumper:Dumper(\$@)";
}

##
# process_request - for Net::Server
sub process_request {
  my $self = shift;
  my $serverProp = $self->{'server'};

  # howto check if ssl session is established?

  while(1) {
    # wait until new data is available
    # read/verify the header (5 byte)
    # read/verify the payload (XX byte)
    # do something with the payload
  };

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Override [`read`](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Net-Server/Net/Server/Proto/SSLEAY.pm.html#read-) to check for a closed connection.
2. Override [`bind_SSL`](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Net-Server/Net/Server/Proto/SSLEAY.pm.html#bind_SSL-) to conduct extra Net::SSLeay checks.